# C# Display Only Specific Items from a Data Source in CheckBoxList

Tags: c#

I'm binding a `CheckBoxList` in a Winform to a data source. However, instead of displaying all items from that source in the list, I'd like to be able to pick out only the ones I really want. I'm stumped on how to do that, or if it can even be done.

Right now the `CheckBoxList` is set-up and bound to a data source like so:

```
((ListBox)this.cblFormType).DataSource = formTypeData;
((ListBox)this.cblFormType).DisplayMember = "ProductClassName";
((ListBox)this.cblFormType).ValueMember = "ProductClass";
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to filter your DataSource before binding

Comment: What is `formTypeData`? Probably you can use LINQ  to choose only the data you want, something like `formTypeData.Where(condition).ToList()`

Comment: Thanks, guys! I'll try filtering the data source before binding it.